# I want to change the shape of my dataset from (N, 512) to (N, 16, 32)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset that has shape (6011, 512). It's an dataframe of 6011 pieces of music with 512 features each.

I want to make my dataset 3 dimensional, which I think would look like (6011, 16, 32) I think.

How do I do this? Would I need to reshape using numpy? I'm doing this since I want to try to put my data through ResNet, but from what I understand ResNet requires a 2D matrix

Comment: Try df.to_numpy().reshape(16,32) to see if that works

Comment: Why are you using Pandas? This sounds like a job for NumPy, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 2D case

Suppose you have an array of integers, 1 to 512, that's 1D:

```
a = np.arange(1, 512+1)
```

Now you can reshape it to the desired size using `a.reshape(n_rows, n_cols)`:

```
b = a.reshape(16,32)
```

Now `b` looks like this:

```
array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,
         14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,
         27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32],
       [ 33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,
         46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,
         59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64],
       [ 65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,
         78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,
         91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96],

       ...

       [449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461,
        462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474,
        475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480],
       [481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493,
        494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506,
        507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512]])
```

### 3D case

To reshape data that has an additional dimension that you want held constant, pass `-1` as the size of that dimension. So, if you have 6011 arrays with 512 elements, like this,

```
a = np.array([np.arange(1,512+1)]*6011)
```

then the 6011 dimension will be first:

```
>>> np.shape(a)
(6011, 512)
```

and you can reshape by passing a `-1` as the first argument, then the values for the two dimensions you want to reshape:

```
b = a.reshape(-1, 32, 16)
```

and `b` now looks like this:

```
array([[[  1,   2,   3, ...,  14,  15,  16],
        [ 17,  18,  19, ...,  30,  31,  32],
        [ 33,  34,  35, ...,  46,  47,  48],
        ...,
        [465, 466, 467, ..., 478, 479, 480],
        [481, 482, 483, ..., 494, 495, 496],
        [497, 498, 499, ..., 510, 511, 512]],

       [[  1,   2,   3, ...,  14,  15,  16],
        [ 17,  18,  19, ...,  30,  31,  32],
        [ 33,  34,  35, ...,  46,  47,  48],
        ...,
        [465, 466, 467, ..., 478, 479, 480],
        [481, 482, 483, ..., 494, 495, 496],
        [497, 498, 499, ..., 510, 511, 512]],

       ...,

       [[  1,   2,   3, ...,  14,  15,  16],
        [ 17,  18,  19, ...,  30,  31,  32],
        [ 33,  34,  35, ...,  46,  47,  48],
        ...,
        [465, 466, 467, ..., 478, 479, 480],
        [481, 482, 483, ..., 494, 495, 496],
        [497, 498, 499, ..., 510, 511, 512]],

       [[  1,   2,   3, ...,  14,  15,  16],
        [ 17,  18,  19, ...,  30,  31,  32],
        [ 33,  34,  35, ...,  46,  47,  48],
        ...,
        [465, 466, 467, ..., 478, 479, 480],
        [481, 482, 483, ..., 494, 495, 496],
        [497, 498, 499, ..., 510, 511, 512]]])
```